# Hiding content until MathJax is complete

Tags: jquery, http-status-code-404, mathjax, url.action

My website has a good amount of MathJax, and I am using the following code to prevent certain objects from being visible on the page until all of the MathJax formulas have been rendered.

```
$("#myDiv").load('@Url.Action("ActionResultMethod", "ControllerName",{controller parameters})', function () {
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(
    ["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"myDiv"],
    function () {
      $("#myDiv").fadeIn(300); 
    }
  );
});
```

In particular, I have a div with the ID `myDiv`, and the page loads with its `display` set to `none`. The code above makes the div fade in when MathJax has finished rendering.

I copied this code from  [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-docs/wiki/Hiding-content-until-typesetting-is-complete).

It is working perfectly, but now when I inspect an element on my page I see the following error in the console.

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/@Url.Action(%22ActionResultMethod%22,
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Note: I have replaced my actual website url with `mywebsite.com`.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it? To reiterate, the code seems to be working perfectly, and I don't detect any problems. I just see this error.

You can see this in action in the following [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tm452dzk/1/). If you inspect an element on the page you'll see the same error in the console.

EDIT: I would also be interested to know if anyone has a way to accomplish this same task with MathJax, but without using @Url.Action, as it seems to be the thing causing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around I realized that the code I copied is good, but the @Url.Action part is unnecessary for what I am trying to do.

In particular, I just deleted everything around `MathJax.Hub.Queue`, as well as the part in brackets. So the code is now just:

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(
  function () {
    $("#myDiv").fadeIn(300); 
  }
);
```

This seems to be working just as well, and I don't have the error message in the console. See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tm452dzk/3/).

All in all this seems like a pretty good solution for using jQuery to delay displaying an object until after MathJax has rendered.